# Here is a problem with the factorial code that I made with Prolog

Tags: recursion, prolog, factorial

I concocted two codes to calculate the factorial with Prolog.
The first is

```
factorial(0, 1).
factorial(N, Result) :-
   N > 0, factorial(N - 1, Interim), Result is N * Interim.
```

, and the second is

```
factorial(0, 1).
factorial(N, Result) :-
   N > 0, M is N - 1, factorial(M, Interim), Result is N * Interim.
```

While the first code had a stack overflow error, the second code ran normally.

I made the following code for the test.

```
sum_2(N, R) :- R is N + 2.
sum_f(N, R) :- sum_2(N + 2, R).
```

The above code was executed normally.

I don't understand why the first code for calculating the factorial is a stack overflow error.

I'd appreciate it if you could tell me why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure that you get a stack overflow with the first version? How are you calling it? A call like `factorial(5, Result)` should fail, i.e., result in an answer like `false` or `no`.

Prolog doesn't "evaluate expressions" like other programming languages. A term like `N - 1` is just data: A term with the functor `-` and two arguments `N` and `1`.  Even if `N` is bound to some number, say `5`, the term is still just `5 - 1` and not `4`. It is *only* mapped to `4` if you specifically ask the `is` predicate or one of the arithmetic comparison predicates (`>`, `=<`, `=:=`, etc.) to evaluate it.

So if you call your first `factorial` predicate as `factorial(5, Result)`, the following things happen:

- the goal `factorial(5, Result)` does not unify with `factorial(0, 1)`, this clause is skipped
- the goal `factorial(5, Result)` unifies with `factorial(N, Result)` with unifier `N = 5`, the body of this clause is executed with this binding

  - the goal `5 > 0` succeeds
  - the call `factorial(5 - 1, Interim)` is executed:

    - the goal `factorial(5 - 1, Interim)` does not unify with `factorial(0, 1)`, this clause is skipped
    - the goal `factorial(5 - 1, Interim)` unifies with `factorial(N, Result)` with unifier `N = 5 - 1` and `Interim = Result`, the body of this clause is executed with this binding

      - the goal `5 - 1 > 0` succeeds
      - the call `factorial((5 - 1) - 1, Interim)` is executed:

        - ...

This ends up calling `factorial` with ever larger terms `5`, `5 - 1`, `(5 - 1) - 1`, `((5 - 1) - 1) - 1`, and so on. Since none of these terms ever unifies with `0`, the computation can never succeed. Since each of these terms unifies with a fresh copy of `N`, the second clause always matches, but eventually you reach a term containing enough `- 1` steps so that the goal `N > 0` will fail, and the query `factorial(5, Result)` will fail.